# Repeat dplyr code snippet x number of times r

Tags: r

Is it possible to repeat lines of code a specific number of times?  Let's say just for an example I want to remove, one at a time, up to 10 lines of mtcars data that has '1' in the mpg column or a 2 in the wt column, running test first and then test2 and starting over.  If one of test or test2 runs out of rows, we will still need to complete the other.

```
test <-mtcars %>% filter(str_detect(mpg, "1"))%>% slice(tail(row_number(),1))
mtcars <- anti_join(mtcars, test, by = c("mpg"))

test2 <-mtcars %>% filter(str_detect(wt, "2"))%>% slice(tail(row_number(),1))
mtcars <- anti_join(mtcars, test2, by = c("wt"))
```

I admit that I am inexperienced with trying to do this sort of thing.  I've seen a couple other examples but I can't really figure out how to apply something like creating a function to what I'm trying to do.

UPDATE:

Here is a little better example.  I have a few of these are adding to one big data frame one at a time.  I need to rerun each block a number of times to populate the data frame.

```
test <-iris %>% filter(str_detect(iris$Petal.Length, "1"))
testa <-test%>%slice(tail(row_number(),1))
iris <- anti_join(iris, testa, by = c("Petal.Length"))
bigdf <- rbind(testa)
```

Comment: Is there a reason you want to remove one row at a time rather than all the rows matching the filter condition at once? If you could just remove 10 rows at once, would that work (and, if so, would you want to use both conditions at once, or the first and then the second up to 10 rows)? Also, you can change `slice(tail(row_number(),1))` to `slice(n())`.

Comment: It's just an example, admittedly probably not a perfect one.  I am trying to figure out how to do this for an example with tons more data that is unfortunately confidential.

Comment: BTW: `slice(tail(row_number(),1))` can be replaced with `tail(1)` or `slice(n())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider a loop to repeat execution of code a specific number of times.

```
for (i in 1:10) {
    test <-mtcars %>% filter(str_detect(mpg, "1"))%>% slice(tail(row_number(),1))
mtcars <- anti_join(mtcars, test, by = c("mpg"))
}
```

For example the above code will be repeated 10 times.

Comment: Awesomely simple & works as I need it to, thank you for taking the time!